# How to load all server side data on initial vue.js / vue-router load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, vue.js

I'm currently making use of the WordPress REST API, and vue-router to transition between pages on a small single page site. However, when I make an AJAX call to the server using the REST API, the data loads, but only after the page has already rendered.

The [vue-router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html) provides insight in regards to how to load data before and after navigating to each route, but I'd like to know how to load all route and page data on the initial page load, circumventing the need to load data each time a route is activated.

Note, I'm loading my data into the `acf` property, and then accessing it within a `.vue` file component using `this.$parent.acfs`.

**main.js Router Code:**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: Home },
        { path: '/about', component: About },
        { path: '/tickets', component: Tickets },
        { path: '/sponsors', component: Sponsors },
    ],
    hashbang: false
});

exports.router = router;

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    data: {
        acfs: ''
    },
    created() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/placeholder/wp-json/acf/v2/page/2',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                this.acfs = response.acf;
                // this.backgroundImage = response.acf.background_image.url
            }.bind(this)
        })
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

**Home.vue Component Code:**

```
export default {
    name: 'about',
    data () {
        return {
            acf: this.$parent.acfs,
        } 
    },
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I finally figured this thing out. All I'm doing is calling a synchronous ajax request within my `main.js` file where my root vue instance is instantiated, and assigning a data property the requested data as so:

**main.js**

```
let acfData;

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'http://localhost/placeholder/wp-json/acf/v2/page/2',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.acf);
        acfData = response.acf;
    }.bind(this)
})  

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: Home },
        { path: '/about', component: About },
        { path: '/tickets', component: Tickets },
        { path: '/sponsors', component: Sponsors },
    ],
    hashbang: false
});

exports.router = router;

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    data: {
        acfs: acfData 
    },
    created() {

    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

From here, I can use the pulled data within each individual `.vue` file / component like so:

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    data () {
    return {
        acf: this.$parent.acfs,
    }
},
```

Finally, I render the data within the same `.vue` template with the following:

```
<template>
  <transition
      name="home"
      v-on:enter="enter"
      v-on:leave="leave"
      v-bind:css="false"
      mode="out-in"
    >
    <div class="full-height-container background-image home" v-bind:style="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.acf.home_background_image.url + ')'}">
      <div class="content-container">
        <h1 class="white bold home-title">{{ acf.home_title }}</h1>
        <h2 class="white home-subtitle">{{ acf.home_subtitle }}</h2>
        <div class="button-block">
          <a href="#/about"><button class="white home-button-1">{{ acf.link_title_1 }}</button></a>
          <a href="#/tickets"><button class="white home-button-2">{{ acf.link_title_2 }}</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>
```

The most important piece of information to take away, is that all of the ACF data is only being called ONCE at the very beginning, compared to every time a route is visited using something like `beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next)`. As a result, I'm able to get silky smooth page transitions as desired.

Hope this helps whoever comes across the same problem.

Answer (score 65):

My approach is to delay construction of the store and main Vue until my AJAX call has returned.

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';

Vue.use(Vuex);

function builder(data) {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      exams: data,
    },
    actions,
    getters,
    mutations,
  });
}

export default builder;
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(VueResource);

Vue.http.options.root = 'https://miguelmartinez.com/api/';

Vue.http.get('data')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    /* eslint-disable no-new */
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      store: store(data),
      template: '<App/>',
      components: { App },
    });
  });
```

I have used this approach with other frameworks such as Angular and ExtJS.

Comment: This is pretty clever.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for this. I learned Webpack/Vue/vue-cli in 12 hours, but couldn't get Vuex understood and working right for three days. Until THIS. Nice answer @Miguel

Comment: Nice! I also did this... i'm only here because I wasn't sure if it was good practice or not but it's good to see someone else thinks its a good idea.

Comment: This worked great for me. Like @Phil I wonder if it's considered good practice. Anyone know?

Comment: If you don't want to make `store` a builder, you can call `store.commit('set_exams', data)` once your ajax promise resolves. This assumes you have a relevant mutation to do this.

Comment: but this does not work with new version of vue because `http` was removed

Comment: @NtwariClaranceLiberiste you can either use `fetch()` in the browser or import something like Axios to make the API call instead of `Vue.http()`

Comment: This is clever, but the only problem I see is that if the user has a slow network connection, they'll be staring at a blank white screen until the response finally returns.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html).

On a specific component, it would look like this:

```
export default {
    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
        // my ajax call
    }
};
```

You can also add a navigation guard to all components:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // my ajax call
});
```

One thing to remember is that navigation guards are async, so you need to call the `next()` callback when the data loading is finished. A real example from my app (where the guard function resides in a separate file):

```
export default function(to, from, next) {
    Promise.all([
        IngredientTypes.init(),
        Units.init(),
        MashTypes.init()
    ]).then(() => {
        next();
    });
};
```

In your case, you'd need to call `next()` in the `success` callback, of course.

Comment: So if I'm using `router.beforeEach()`, where should I be storing my AJAX response data? Is there a route object I should be storing it in like `$route.params`?

Comment: Also, is there a way to ensure the data is only loaded once, rather than multiple times when you switch back and forth between pages?

Comment: I use service classes for that (`IngredientTypes` etc.). They store the data and any component can use them. When they already have data stored, they just don't send another request, but rather immediately return a resolved promise. I also know that there's a tool for state management called vuex, which in theory might also help you achieve what you're after, but I haven't used it, so I can't offer any solid information on it.

Comment: Friendly warning; this gets really messy, really fast

Comment: @ZacJacob... wish I saw your warning 2 years ago, cause you were right. It got f'kin messy

Answer (score 6):

I've comprised my own version based on all the great responses to this post.. and several years having passed by as well giving me more tools.

In **main.js**, I use async/await to call a prefetch service to load any data that must be there on startup. I find this increases readability. After I get the data **comms**, I then dispatch it to the appropriate vuex store module in the beforeCreate() hook.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

import { prefetchAppData } from '@/services/prefetch.service';

(async () => {
    let comms = await prefetchAppData();

    new Vue({
        router,
        store,
        beforeCreate() {
            store.dispatch('communityModule/initialize', comms);
        },
        mounted() {},
        render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app');
})();
```

*I feel compelled to warn those be careful what you prefetch. Try to do this sparingly as it does delay initial app loading which is not ideal for a good user experience.*

Here's my sample **prefetch.service.js** which does the data load. This of course could be more sophisticated.

```
import api from '@api/community.api';
export async function prefetchAppData() {
    return await api.getCommunities();
}
```

A simple vue store. This store maintains a list of 'communities' that the app requires to be loaded before application start.

**community.store.js** (note im using vuex modules)

```
export const communityModule = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        communities: []
    },
    getters: {
        communities(state) {
            return state.communities;
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_COMMUNITIES(state, communities) {
            state.communities = communities;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        // instead of loading data here, it is passed in 
        initialize({ commit }, comms) {
            commit('SET_COMMUNITIES', comms);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this section in docs of Vue Router

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html

So first of you have to write method that would fetch data from your endpoint, and then use watcher to watch route.

```
export default {
    watch: {
        '$route': 'fetchItems'
    },
    methods: {
        fetchItems() {
          // fetch logic
        }
    }
}
```

Since you are working with WP Rest API, feel free to check my repo on Github https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp/blob/master/public/app/themes/vuewp/app/views/PostView.vue#L39