# Asynchronous new Vue() to wait for initial authentication

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I am quite new to Vue and currently setting up an app that uses firebase authentication and firestore for basic RBAC.
To prevent unauthorized users from entering routes my router has a custom AuthGuard inspecting the local users roles (The backend implements similar rules)

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/users',
      name: 'Users',
      component: Users,
      beforeEnter: AuthGuard(user => user.uid && user.roles.admin)
    }
..
]})
```

One issue I have with this setup is that sending people links to protected pages does not work. The auth guard prevents them from loading the page because the local `user` is not set initialized when the Vue app initializes.

So I came up with a *way* to delay the creation of my Vue App by structuring my `main.js` something along:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
...
init()
.then(() => new Vue(..)
```

During the `init` function I am waiting for `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` to fire and tell me if the user has a valid token or not. It *does* work but it does not feel right.

Is it ok to asynchronously create a new Vue App? Are there better methods like lazy loading the authentication guard on the route or something?

Answer (score 1):

I do the same with Vue and Azure Active Directory authentication, seems to be the best way of doing it.

Please see Miguels answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45899653/2703700

Is that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Definitely helps knowing others do the same. Thanks Tim :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same thing as well. Here's a snippet in case someone is interested in a more concrete example:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'

/**
 * Initialize Firebase
 */

firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG)

/**
 * Initialize Vue.js
 */

let app;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (!app) {
    app = new Vue({
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#dashboard')
  }
})
```