# Vue JS Technique for making data available on application load from different entry points

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Looking for a technique or best practice for loading data that is needed throughout application **on application load**. The desired data is needed on app entry which can be from many different entry points.

What I have tried:

1. Making an api call in the `app.vue` component. The result here was that in many cases the "inner" components are actually loaded first so my data was not there.
2. Making an api call on store init, here too the same result as above.
3. My actual solution (not great) was to simply call in specific components when the data was not there, this was dependant on the users navigation, at times it was already there (saved in store) due to the fact the user was already at a previous page and at times (e.g. a refresh) it wasn't there and needed to be reloaded. in general putting `v-if` on specific components seems like a hack to me and I do not like this solution.

Ideally I would like to be able to handle this shared data somewhere centrally (like a store) and most importantly have it load *before* the components load. Can this be accomplished with vue? How?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load all server side data on initial vue.js / vue-router load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572974/how-to-load-all-server-side-data-on-initial-vue-js-vue-router-load)

Comment: yes it does answer the question!