# vue.js performance issue - loading menus slowly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Vue.js v2.6.11, i'm facing performance issues with loading the menus.
I need to load the menus as fast as i can but currently it's taking on production server more than 1 sec to load. below is my current code of loading the menus.

is there any way to give loading the menus the most priority ? i tried v-once but the menu didn't render

thanks in advance.

Vuejs

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    i18n,
    data: {
    ...
        menus: [],
    ...
    },
    methods: {
        ...
    },
    async mounted() {
    ...
        axios.get("...../getMenus")
            .then(response => { this.menus = response.data; });
        ...
    },
    computed: {
        ...
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" v-for="m in menus.top" v-cloak>
    <a v-if="m.childs.length > 0" class="nav-link text-white dropdown-toggle" :href="m.m_link" :target="m.m_target" :id="m.m_id" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{m.m_name}}</a>
    <a v-else class="nav-link text-white" :target="m.m_target" :href="m.m_link">{{m.m_name}}</a>
    <div v-if="m.childs.length > 0" class="dropdown-menu" :aria-labelledby="m.m_id">
        <a class="dropdown-item" :href="sm.m_link" :target="m.sm_target" v-for="sm in m.childs">{{sm.m_name}}</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Try moving the API call to created hooks. If still doesn't solves the problem, follow the solution in the given link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572974/how-to-load-all-server-side-data-on-initial-vue-js-vue-router-load

Comment: well, actually replacing mounted with created was a good idea it improves the load time :) thx